# Exchange impersonation rights

Tags: exchange, impersonation

I need an answer to the following quetsion: What rights are required for Exchange Impersonation? I know this is kind of vague, but I really need an answer...

Answer (score 1):

The **ApplicationImpersonation** right. It's right there [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/bb204095%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx).